# Como fazer commit apenas em um pedaço de um arquivo no Git?

Tags: git, commit

Ao modificar várias partes de um arquivo, é possível dar commit em apenas um pedaço (por exemplo, uma nova função)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilize `git add --patch <nome_do_arquivo>` (ou `git add -p <nome_do_arquivo>`). Desta maneira, o **git** irá permitir que o usuário defina, interativamente, qual parte do código será adicionado para o commit. Então, tecle um dos seguintes comandos:

```
y - aplicar 'stage' ao bloco
n - ignorar bloco
q - sair; ignorar este e todos outros blocos
a - aplicar 'stage' neste bloco e em todos os próximos
d - ignorar bloco atual e todos os que estão a frente
g - ir até um bloco
/ - buscar por um bloco dada uma expressão regular
j - deixar bloco como não resolvido, ir para próximo bloco não resolvido
J - deixar bloco como não resolvido, ir para próximo bloco
k - deixar bloco como não resolvido, ir para bloco não resolvido anterior
K - deixar bloco como não resolvido, ir para bloco anterior
s - dividir bloco em partes menores
e - editar bloco manualmente
? - imprimir ajuda
```

Se o arquivo não estiver no repositório, use o comando `git add -N <nome_do_arquivo>`.

Para verificar as mudanças, utilize o comando `git diff --staged`.

*Obs: inspirado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085191/604734) do Stack Overflow em inglês.*